# How to match with DataSet row in c#?

Tags: c#, dataset, row

Here `ab.ABNumber` is counting from the 1st row of dataset And  `dr["ABNumber"].ToString()` is counting from last row. For that my condition is always mismatched. How can I do it for matched with my condition.

```
public bool EmailAuthorization(ABMaster ab) 
{   
   string ids = string.Empty;
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   ds= new   ABMasterService().LoadAllMDPendingAuthorization(ab.ID);

   foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
   {
      if (ab.ABNumber == dr["ABNumber"].ToString())
      {
         if (ids.Length > 0)
         {
            ids += ",";
         }
         ids += ab.ABNumber;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: We can't help because we don't know what `ab.ABNumber` is and what the `ABNumber`-column of this table contains. Maybe there are invisible characters or something like that. Use the debugger.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What's `ab.ABNumber`? What's the problem?

Comment: ABNumber  is a Record of ABMaster Table of Database  and my given ds generate two record in ds from another table Pending of same database and relation with two table ID  of ABMaster And ABID of Pending . I need to  match the record within both table. But When i start looping it's showing two record and when i make  if (ab.ABNumber == dr["ABNumber"].ToString()) . ab.ABNumber get the 1st row of dataset &  dr["ABNumber"] get the last row. For this it's showing mismatched.

Answer (score 1):

If `ab.ABNumber` should really be a string you should compare this strings with `Equals`

```
ab.ABNumber.Equals(dr["ABNumber"].ToString())
```